# OS-independent bzip2-compression of an external file using R?

Tags: r, compression, bzip2

For standardized packaging of in-house data and its analysis, I'm writing an `R` function generating a customized package skeleton.

One task I have is to integrated tab-delimited data files in the `inst/extdata` sub-directory of the packaging infrastructure (this is not to discuss the appropriateness or lack thereof of this strategy, please).

To that end I'm looking for a OS/CLI-independent way to compress those files using bzip2 - analogous to the `bunzip2` command in the `R.utils` package - and have come up with nothing not utilizing `system` and `bzip2` outside of `R`.

Can anyone point at a solution?

Comment: `system` & `bzip2` look fine to me.

Comment: OS-independence/self containment is not given and I'd prefer that.

Comment: You probably should look for some *R* wrapper or glue code for [libbzip2](http://www.bzip.org/)

Comment: `tar` seems to (somewhat) deliver what I want - at the expense of producing `tar`ed output (in addition to `bzip`ing).